# Extract line from RichtextBox into Another Richtextbox

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox

I have a windows form Application with two richtextboxes. I am able to display a text file in one of them but my problem is i want to select certain lines from the first box into the second box.

For example, the first box contains lines like:

```
Timestamp
----
------
------
Main issues
```

I want to be able to select the "timestamp" line and the line containing "main issue" into the second richtextbox.

This is what i have so far:
 private void btn_GetValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        int counter = 0;

        String search;

        //textBox1.Text = strfilename;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (System.IO.StreamReader search = new System.IO.StreamReader(textDisplayArea.Text))
        {
            while ((line = search.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains("'Timestamp', 'main battery', 'Expansion battery'"))
                    sb.AppendLine(search.ToString());
            }
        }
        richTextBox_Regex.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
```

This is not working for me.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please edit your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you or suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Actually (since i am just learning C#) I am trying to do a string select from one richtext box to another but i seem to be running into difficulty.

Comment: And what difficulty would that be? Please [edit] your post to include a question and any additional information you have.

Comment: The post have been editted with the codes i have so far